# Splitting a string from url pattern

Tags: java

I have a string in the format: /constant/variableurl . What is the best way out, such that, I can get the variableurl alone as a string.

I understand string tokenizer and regex are the two way out, but not sure how to split the last variableurl alone.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you show three or four example strings, along with the results that you want to see?

Comment: `String lastvar = mystring.substring((mystring.lastIndexOf('/'))+1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your explanation and example this is code that you could use (not perfect, generic)

`toFind.substring(toFind.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)`

where
`String toFind = "/constant/variableurl"`

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve that:

```
String[] res = myStr.split("\\/");
String myStr = res[res.length - 1];
```

---

```
myStr = myStr.substring(myStr.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

...

To add more methods, visit [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html?is-external=true).

Answer (score 1):

If the constant portion of the string is the same for all your strings, you can get the variable portion of it using `substring`, and passing the length of the common part:

```
String a = "/constant/hello/world";
String b = "/constant/quick/brown/fox";
String c = "/constant/jumps/over/the/lazy/dog";
int len = "/constant/".length(); // That's 10
a = a.substring(len);            // Becomes "hello/world"
b = a.substring(len);            // Becomes "quick/brown/fox"
c = a.substring(len);            // Becomes "jumps/over/the/lazy/dog"
```